# Error connecting Robot Framework to MS SQL Server database

Tags: database, robotframework, pymssql

I am somewhat experienced with Robot Framework, but new to the idea of connecting it to databases. I am trying to create a basic database test in my organization using Robot Framework in the PyCharm IDE. I've written the test using pymssql. It gives an unusual error message when it fails. I've read that I might need to install FreeTDS to do this, but I would prefer not to if I don't absolutely have to. I have seen several answers to this kind of question from Python developers, but I've not seen any who are using Robot Framework specifically.

Versions:
PyCharm 2020.1
Python 3.8.
Pymssql version 2.1.5.

Here is my code and the error messages I am getting.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       DB Suite
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Library             DatabaseLibrary
Resource            ../../Pages/xxx/resource.robot

*** Variables ***
${DBName}           DBxxx
${DBUser}           USER xxx
${DBPass}           PASS xxx
${DBHost}           localhost
${DBPort}           1433

*** Test Cases ***
TC 001 Database Check
    Connect To Database     pymssql     ${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}
    ${output}=              Execute SQL String      select * from dbo.xxx;
    Log To Console          ${output}
    Disconnect From Database
```

And here is the error message:

OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10061)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10061)\n')

I have read elsewhere that this error means that my Pymssql just can't find the server, but I've seen Pymssql not throw these errors before in other tutorials. It just connects right away. Anybody got any ideas on this one? I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: The error implies it can't connect to the server on your machine. Are you sure the server is running on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I can manually connect to the db with no problems

Comment: What do you mean by "manually", and when you say "the db" are you referring to the db running directly on your machine? Have you searched this site for the error "Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist "? When I do, I get several questions and answers. Are none of them helpful?

Comment: I use SSMS to connect to my database, which is at my home office. Remote from me. But I can still connect if I fire up SSMS and log in on my own. I have looked around for the "Adaptive Server is unavailable" message, but that's usually referring to Python code specifically, not a Robot Framework issue. It doesn't seem like it would help, cause I'm using Robot. I'm thinking there's something wrong in how I"m telling Robot Framework to connect. But I keep running into the same answers that don't apply to me.

Comment: Ok, well the way you seem to have robot configured, it's looking for the db on localhost, not on a remote machine.  Also, the robot keywords are written in python.